# How to properly allocate memory for structs, arrays of structs inside a struct, and passing that array as a parameter

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I've been quite aways away from C and as I am diving back into it I have found myself hitting a roadblock. I have the following structure:

```
typedef struct{
      char id;
      struct S *children[SIZE];
}S;
```

In my code I initially declare an array of structs...

```
 struct S arr[SIZE];
```

But when I get to this point of trying to allocate my first child for my first member of arr...

```
 arr[0].children[0] = (S*)malloc(sizeof(S));
```

I get this warning: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’ warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

On top of this I'm getting an error that doesn't sound very logical to me. I have the following function:

```
int foo(S *children[SIZE]);
```

but when I call this line....

```
foo(arr[0].children);
```

I get this note: note: expected ‘struct S **’ but argument is of type ‘struct S **’
which to me just sounds silly, it is expecting the argument it is getting and is upset about it.

Any help in explaining what I should be doing to properly allocate this memory and achieve the same idea would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You don't have an array of structs inside your struct. You have an array of pointers. That makes a big difference.

Comment: Before you define the type-alias `S`, where do you declare the structure `S`? I'm actually surprised you don't get compiler *errors* as inside the structure there is no structure named `S`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `struct S`, only `S` which is a `typedef` of anonymous structure.

Define `struct S` too:

```
typedef struct S {
  char id;
  struct S *children[SIZE];
}S;
```

Or:

```
typedef struct S S;
struct S {
  char id;
  S *children[SIZE];
};
```

And [do avoid casting return of malloc in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/694733):

```
arr[0].children[0] = malloc(sizeof(S));
```

Comment: So when I go with the second option, it is now telling me it is expecting '{' before ';' and that there is an expected specifier-qualifier-list before '*' token

Comment: On struct definition? Strange. I am not getting compiler warning. Try putting, `struct` back to declaration of children. Cyclical type definitions are a little troublesome sometimes.

Comment: Okay I found out why it was giving me that weird one, it was my bad when I was trying something else. But with that second option it not tells me error: ‘S’ redeclared as different kind of symbol

Comment: @WarGravy you have some other code which also defines `S` then.

Comment: Yeah so in the compiler, it tells me where my reference is, and it is saying that Struct S{...}; was defined on the line: typedef struct S S;

Comment: The good thing is my previous errors are gone now and it is just this last duplicate reference thing.

Comment: Ah so I was able to get the first one to work. Thank you everyone!

Comment: I do remember one embedded compiler (but not what it was) that deviated from C standard: It didn't use separated namespaces for structures. It meant that `struct S` and `typedef ... S` would collide. I had use different names for those like `typedef struct SS TS`.

Answer (score 1):

For your first problem, you need to do:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

at the top of your program, in order to call `malloc` successfully.

The second problem (as also pointed out by others) is that `struct S` in your class definition refers to a different struct than `S`.  In C, struct tags are in a different "namespace" than type names.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful. I did not know about the namespace